# What is reason for below error?

Tags: iphone

```
ImageIO: CGImageRead_mapData 'open' failed '/Users/Vyom/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/47042F21-2B0F-4A18-8950-369E60C07481/MemoryGame.app/card_back.png'

error = 24 (Too many open files)
```

I am developing game in Xcode and it's fresh after 3 level and show me above error. Can any tell what is problem.

Comment: You should include a snippet of the code where the error is happening to help people help you.

Answer (score 1):

The error says "too many open files". You need to close the files when you're done reading from them otherwise you run out of file handles.

Comment: Yes that is right but i have 12 images and 12 buttons so when i click on button i have to open images.and i need all these images trough out my project.so i can not release before view is unload.it's consider my openimage function as file.Thanks For Help